# how to use ul li ng-repeat inside directive using append

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

how to append `ul li ng-repeat` at directive angularjs?
This is my array list.

```
var getAreaList = [
          "City",
          "Central",
          "North",
          "South",
          "East",
          "West",
];
```

This is my append :

```
myEl.append("<div ng-init='x="+getAreaList+"' class='clearfix left-align left card-panel blue-text text-darken-2 hoverable'>"<ul><li ng-repeat='x in getAreaList'>{{x}}</li></ul></div>");
```

Help me to see.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By your question its clear that you are looking for a directive to bind your array in ul li using a directive 
So I have made a directive for and also a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/athulnair/m2f2omke/

```
app.directive('ngUl', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
        data:'='
        },
        template: '<div><ul><li ng-repeat="item in data"><span ng-bind="item"></span></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

        }
    }});
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but <ng-ul data='data'></ng-ul> directive tab is not be in initial load of html . Which will append based on some condition is true from directive.

Comment: If there is not data in the initial load then also no issues will occuer. And about the conditions then also you can filter and then you can push it to the $scope.data. If you provide the actual data and filters I am able to help you